# How can I get TOTP into my code (python -post request) and add a hash function

Tags: python, json, authorization, http-post, basic-authentication

so I'm working on this challenge, and I'm having some difficulties. I finished the first two parts of this 3 part challenge but I'm stumped with the 3rd part. I just started learning Python and have never seen this before so I'm quite lost. The rules are to make a JSON string with my email, gist URL, and coding language. That is meant to be in the body of the post request. The post request has these rules:

The Content-Type: of the request must be application/JSON.

Authorization
The URL is protected by HTTP Basic Authentication, which is explained on Chapter 2 of RFC2617, so you have to provide an Authorization: header field in your POST request

For the userid of HTTP Basic Authentication, use the same email address you put in the JSON string.
For the password, provide a 10-digit time-based one time password conforming to RFC6238 TOTP.
Authorization password
For generating the TOTP password, you will need to use the following setup:

You have to read RFC6238 (and the errata too!) and get a correct one time password by yourself.
TOTP's Time Step X is 30 seconds. T0 is 0.
Use HMAC-SHA-512 for the hash function, instead of the default HMAC-SHA-1.
Token shared secret is the userid followed by ASCII string value "STRING" (not including double quotations).

What I have so far after lots of research:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from base64 import b64encode

url = 'https://api.url.com'
payload = {
  "github_url": "https://gist.github.com/gist-url",
  "contact_email": "EMAIL",
  "solution_language": "python"
}
userid = "EMAIL"
name = "STRING"
shared_secret = userid+name
timestep = 30
T0 = 0
header = {"Content-type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": "Basic {}".format(
            b64encode(bytes(f"{userid}:{name}", "utf-8")).decode("ascii"))
          }
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=header)
```

I'm doing this in PYCHARM since thats what I'm using in my uni class if it matters. I'm confused about how to use TOTP (and what it is to be honest) and the hash function to make this work. Right now, if I run this in pycharm I get nothing back.

Comment: You are not getting anything because you aren't doing anything with the response you are getting. Try printing the status code and response after you make the request. `print(r.status_code, r.text)`. TOPT is just `Time-Based One-Time Password Algorithm` which is used in 2FA. To me it reads like you might need to implement your own functions for TOPT. If you don't, you can use this library [PyOTP](https://pyauth.github.io/pyotp/)

Comment: Did you read RFC 6238? If not, I recommend at least reading [1.2.  Background](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238#section-1.2), the entirety of [4. TOTP Algorithm](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238#section-4) and for implementing the `Truncate` function with SHA512 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27474/how-does-the-hotp-dynamic-truncation-function-generalize-to-longer-hashes

Comment: Thank you @0x00 for your reply. printing the status is a good start, I should have thought about it! The library looks promising as well so I'll try it.

Comment: Thank you @DerSchinken for all the links. I read the chapters and have a little more understanfing of what TOTP is although its the implementation that I'm still stuck on. The link to the stack exchange was nice but aside from changing the character count to 64 I'm a little lost on the syntax. I get a "cannot assign to expression here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?" for the `DT(String) // String.......`  part and syntax errors throughout.